# Which ordinals can be "mistaken for" $\aleph_1$?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, cardinals, ordinals, forcing

I've just finished working my way through Weaver's proof of the consistency of the negation of the Continuum Hypothesis in his book *Forcing for Mathematicians*. One of the key points in this proof is that if $\mathrm{M}$ is a countable transitive model of ZFC, then the ordinal numbers in $\mathrm{M}$ are *absolute*, i.e. they are necessarily identical to the ordinal numbers in our larger universe, whereas the cardinal numbers in $\mathrm{M}$ are *relative*, meaning that, for instance, $\aleph_1^M$, or the first ordinal which $\mathrm{M}$ "thinks is uncountable", may be (and in this case actually is) only countable in the outside model.

Since $\mathrm{M}$ only contains countable ordinals, it must be "mistaking" some countable ordinal for $\aleph_1$. What do we know about which countable ordinals can serve as $\aleph_1$ for a countable transitive model of ZFC? Clearly $\omega$ cannot, since $\aleph_0$ is absolute. But which ordinals *can* be mistaken as $\aleph_1$? In particular:

- Can $\omega^2$ be mistaken for $\aleph_1$? Can $\omega^\omega$?
- What is the smallest ordinal that can be mistaken for $\aleph_1$?
- What properties must $\aleph_1^M$ have as an ordinal? (For instance, my intuition tells me that it must be a limit ordinal, not a successor ordinal.)

Can someone either sketch an answer to one or more of these questions (so that I can get an idea of how one goes about answering them), or point me to another resource that does? Thanks!

Comment: Relevant MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347837

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a very natural question, but one which - in my opinion - isn't going to have a satisfying answer: there's good heuristic evidence that no snappier description of this property than its definition exists. I'll use the phrase "$\omega_1$-like" instead of "can be mistaken for $\aleph_1$."

---

First, it's easy to check that $\omega^2$, $\omega^\omega$, $\epsilon_0$, and even "big" countable ordinals like $\omega_1^{CK}$ (= the first "non-computable" ordinal) have absolute definitions. So they aren't $\omega_1$-like. Similarly, being a successor ordinal is absolute, and since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that $\omega_1$ isn't a successor ordinal no successor ordinal can be $\omega_1$-like.

In fact, letting $\eta$ be the least $\omega_1$-like ordinal (and working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a transitive model" to guarantee its existence) there is a general obstacle here to any simple characterization of this $\eta$:

> $(*)\quad$ There is no first-order theory $T$ such that $\eta=\min\{\alpha:L_\alpha\models T\}$.

*Here $L$ is [Godel's constructible hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe). It's worth noting that in fact $(*)$ can be significantly strengthened; for example, we can replace "$L_\alpha\models T$" with "$L_{\alpha^2}\models T$," and so on, without changing the argument.*

We can prove $(*)$ by applying [downward Lowenheim-Skolem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) (+ the [Mostowski collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostowski_collapse_lemma)) run inside $\mathsf{ZFC}$: in any model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, there is a countable-in-$M$ transitive set (necessarily of countable height!) which $M$ thinks has the same first-order theory as $L_{\omega_1}$.

Basically, $\eta$ represents a very complicated phase transition. By contrast, something like $\omega_1^{CK}$ - while extraordinarily huge by most standards - is simple to detect in this way: $\omega_1^{CK}=\min\{\alpha:L_\alpha\models$[$\mathsf{KP}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory)$\mathsf{+Inf}\}$.

Effectively, $(*)$ and its strengthenings rule out any simple description of $\eta$ **other than** its a priori definition; it's just so complicated that we can't hope for something much more concrete.

That said, to get a sense of what you hit *along the way* to $\eta$, see [this summary paper by Madore](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/math/ordinal-zoo.pdf) (note that each ordinal in that paper has an absolute definition). The ordinal $\eta$ here is entry $2.23$ in Madore's list, the third-to-largest ordinal he considers.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Guess it's just another one of those seemingly simple math questions that ends up actually being hopelessly complicated. :P

Comment: Regarding the least $\omega_1$-like ordinal - is being $\omega_1$-like absolute?

Comment: @EdwardH Whoops, quite right. I've deleted that comment for now, I'll fix it when I have time.