# "Size" of Cohen minimal model's closure ordinal?

Tags: set-theory

The description of the Cohen minimal model of ZFC described on pages 8-9 of [this doc](https://math.bu.edu/people/aki/14.pdf) mentions that "the closure ordinal $\gamma$, i.e. the least $\alpha$ such that $T_{\alpha + 1} = T_{\alpha}$, is countable".

My question: is it known more precisely how "big" this closure ordinal is? For example,

- How does it compare to "well-known" ordinals like: the Church-Kleene ordinal $\omega_1^{CK}$, or $\omega_{\alpha}^{CK}$ for $\alpha > 1$, or countable recursively Mahlo ordinals?
- Can it be described by Veblen hierarchy notation or by some even simpler notation (like $\omega^{\omega^{\omega}}$ or $\epsilon_{\epsilon_0}$)?

*Footnote:* This other [answer about ordinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4626060) says "pathologically small" models may have a fairly limited class of (countable) ordinals, and if the Cohen model is indeed "minimal", I guess it qualifies as "pathologically small". So maybe the aforementioned closure ordinal $\gamma$ is fairly small? (maybe $\leq \omega_1^{CK}$?)

Comment: As a transitive model of set theory it must agree with the universe on arithmetic statements, in particular, any recursive ordinal must be inside this model, and so $\omega_1^{CK}$ must be there too, and by applying some set theory to it, you can show that a lot more has to be in this model. Satisfying ZFC is not a small feat for a countable transitive model.

Comment: I see. Now, given that the closure ordinal must be "a lot more" than $\omega_1^{CK}$, is it possible to put any bounds on how *much* more? Or is this a situation where it can be proven that that a countable $\gamma$ such that $T_{\gamma + 1} = T_{\gamma}$ *exists*, but there's no (known) way to establish its value with any specificity?